# Windows 11 (and Win 10) Force showing already paired bluetooth devices in add a device screen

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, bluetooth

The situation is this:

1. Connect PS5 controller (ANY bluetooth device!) to windows -> comes up in add a device -> pairs fine
2. Connect the bluetooth device to my switch (or to android phone, another computer)
3. Connect that previously paired bluetooth device to the original Win 11 (or Win 10) computer -> does NOT show up in add a device

I believe the WHY of this problem is windows sees the device is *already paired*, so it does not display it in add a device screen even though the device is in pair mode. **Android does this better** by ALWAYS showing a device in pair mode, and when paired simply throws out the old pairing info and re-adds it to the device list. **This behavior is what I want to hack/modify/alter windows to do.**

There is a workaround to this that is ***not a solution***: Remove the device, THEN try to re-pair it. If you only have one controller connected this works fine. I repair ps4/5 controllers and often have 30 or 40 controllers on the pair list. If I want to reconnect my personal controller after using it with my switch, I often need to remove **literally dozens** of devices one by one from my devices list hoping I hit the controller in question.

Does anyone have a solution to making re-pairing an already paired bluetooth device on windows 11 (and win 10!) less tedious?

Comment: Does the Bluetooth dialog help? Make a shortcut to it as `ms-settings:bluetooth`.